# MSVC insists on using inaccessible member from private-inherited base class, although it was re-defined as public

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider this code ([godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/frzj1171q)):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

template< std::size_t... sizes >
class Impl
{
public:
    static constexpr std::size_t
    getDimension()
    {
        return sizeof...( sizes );
    }
};

template< std::size_t... sizes >
class Wrapper : private Impl< sizes... >
{
    using BaseType = Impl< sizes... >;

public:
    //using BaseType::getDimension;
    static constexpr std::size_t
    getDimension()
    {
        return BaseType::getDimension();
    }
};

template< typename A, typename B >
class Combine : public B
{
public:
    static_assert( A::getDimension() > 0 );
    static_assert( B::getDimension() > 0 );
    static_assert( A::getDimension() == B::getDimension(),
                   "dimensions of A and b do not match" );
};

int main()
{
    Combine< Impl< 0 >, Wrapper< 0 > > a;
}
```

Trying to compile with MSVC (v19 with `/std:c++17 /permissive-`) leads to this error:

```
example.cpp
<source>(32): error C2247: 'Impl<0>::getDimension' not accessible because 'Wrapper<0>' uses 'private' to inherit from 'Impl<0>'
<source>(8): note: see declaration of 'Impl<0>::getDimension'
<source>(40): note: see declaration of 'Wrapper<0>'
<source>(40): note: see declaration of 'Impl<0>'
<source>(32): error C2248: 'Impl<0>::getDimension': cannot access private member declared in class 'Wrapper<0>'
<source>(8): note: see declaration of 'Impl<0>::getDimension'
<source>(40): note: see declaration of 'Wrapper<0>'
<source>(40): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Combine<Impl<0>,Wrapper<0>>' being compiled
<source>(34): error C2247: 'Impl<0>::getDimension' not accessible because 'Wrapper<0>' uses 'private' to inherit from 'Impl<0>'
<source>(8): note: see declaration of 'Impl<0>::getDimension'
<source>(40): note: see declaration of 'Wrapper<0>'
<source>(40): note: see declaration of 'Impl<0>'
<source>(34): error C2248: 'Impl<0>::getDimension': cannot access private member declared in class 'Wrapper<0>'
<source>(8): note: see declaration of 'Impl<0>::getDimension'
<source>(40): note: see declaration of 'Wrapper<0>'
Compiler returned: 2
```

However, the code compiles fine with state-of-the-art compilers like GCC and Clang, so I assume the code is correct. Is there a workaround for MSVC? Note that the private inheritance has a purpose in the real world.

Comment: Note that - as per msvc, not as per standard - you can't call `Impl<0>::getDimension()` in anything that descends from `Impl<0>` as msvc wants to use the inheritance chain to resolve it. However, you can call it externally. Still, quite annoying I think.

Comment: @lorro I've updated the example - two more static asserts were added. Note that the first one fails, but the second one succeeds. This is even more annoying since inheriting from the `Wrapper` breaks the direct use of `Impl` in the class...

Comment: see my answer below, it works for those as well. But again, it's just a workaround (or two), the proper solution I think is a compiler fix.

Comment: Thanks, it's still better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ugly workaround exists. First, you might define an external template function for delegating to the proper class:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t getDimension()
{
    return T::getDimension();
}
```

This is so that MSVC's name resolution won't try to search in the private base classes. Then, you might write:

```
template< typename A, typename B >
class Combine : public B
{
public:
    static_assert( ::getDimension<A>() == ::getDimension<B>(),
                   "dimensions of A and b do not match" );
};
```

The `::` is not mandatory, it's only for cases where `getDimension()` would also take template arguments as a member function.

This hack uses the fact that it's a `static` member function; if you have a non-static member function, you need to pass `this` as well.

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/4fax9dGvd

---

An alternative solution is to wrap the call to an inner `struct`:

```
template< typename A, typename B >
class Combine : public B
{
public:
    static struct {
        static_assert( A::getDimension() == B::getDimension(),
                       "dimensions of A and b do not match" );
    } verify;
};
```

This does not require a global template function to delegate, but neither is ran direcly inside your `class` (which might or might not be a problem).